# Mechanize error "too many bad responses"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, web-crawler, mechanize

Doing scraping I've found that some urls failed. After check the url looked ok in the browser and see in wireshark the remote server was answering with a 200 I've finally found that the url:

http://www.segundamano.es/electronica-barcelona-particulares/galaxy-note-3-mas.htm

was failing with

```
Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error: too many bad responses after 0 requests on 42319240, last used 1414078471.6468294 seconds ago
```

More weird is that if you remove a character from the last part, it works. If you add the character in another place, it fails again.

**Update 1**

The "code"

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.segundamano.es/electronica-barcelona-particulares/galaxy-note-3.htm")
  Net::HTTP::Persistent::Error: too many bad responses after 0 requests on 41150840, last used 1414079640.353221 seconds ago
```

Comment: This is a network error which normally occurs if you make too many requests to a certain source from the same IP.

Comment: Don't use wireshark, use fiddler or charles.

Comment: @pguardiario Whats the problem with wireshark?

Comment: It's just the wrong tool for debugging http requests. You will go cross-eyed before long.

Comment: Good as an opinion. I'm more used to wireshark than the other tools. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Severin, the problem was in the other side. As I can't do anything in the server, I was trying different libs to fetch the data. It was weird that some of them worked and others don't. Trying different setups for mechanize, at the end I've found a good one:

```
  agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| 
    agent.gzip_enabled = false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a network error which normally occurs if you make too many requests to a certain source from the same IP and thus the page takes too long to load. You could try adding a custom timeout to your connection agent, keep the connection alive and ignore bad chunking (potentially bad):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.keep_alive = true
agent.ignore_bad_chunking = true
agent.open_timeout = 25
agent.read_timeout = 25
page = agent.get("http://www.segundamano.es/electronica-barcelona-particulares/galaxy-note-3.htm")
```

But that is not giving you a guarantee that the connection will be successfull, it just increases the chances.

It's hard to say why you get the error on one url and not on another. When you remove the 3 you request a different page; one that might be easier for the server to process? My point being: There is nothing wrong with your Mechanize setup but with the response you are getting back.

Comment: exactly the same issue. I try with different urls and works fine. Removing the '3' works. I can run both requests a few times and always fails the one with the '3'.

Comment: I want to highlight this part of the error, that I really don't understand: too many bad responses after 0 requests

Comment: The request is failing really fast, even if I set a big timeout. So the error should be something different.

Comment: As I said: There is nothing wrong with your Mechanize setup and there is no way of knowing why their servers behaves like this to your request.